# How to manipulate the expression $16b^3a^2(6ab^4)(ab)^3$ to the form $2^m3^na^rb^s$ (Serge Lange Basic Mathematics, Chap 1 $3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So this chapter has gone over the basic properties of multiplication, but I don't have a great example of how to arrive at the solution in the text for this problem.

Given solution: $2^{10}3^3a^6b^{10}$

I'm not sure how to start it. It's easy for me to keep track of the powers of a and b, but I don't see the steps to reach $2^{10}$ and $3^3$?

In another example $8a^2b^3(27a^4)(2^5ab)$ I tried to simplify it down as much as possible and arrived at $6912a^7b^4$, which is 'correct' but not in the specified form. Was that the right approach? Should I have then tried to break 6912 into $2^x3^x$? If yes, how do you do that?

Comment: Well , $16 = 2^4$ and $6 = 2^1.3^1$ . Do you still don't see the solution ?

Comment: So I see we could then re-write the expression then as $2^4b^3a^2(2^1*3^1ab^4)(ab)^3$. But then what's the next step? Do you mind going step by step? Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

The answer goes back to the [Prime Factor Decomoposition](https://revisionworld.com/gcse-revision/maths/number-and-algebra/number/numbers/prime-factor-decomposition). Observe that $$16\cdot6=2^4\cdot2\cdot3=2^5\cdot 3$$ Notwithstanding, the given solution is *wrong*; it should be

> $$2^5\cdot 3\cdot a^6\cdot b^{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Write $$2^5\times3a^2aa^3b^3b^4b^3=2^5\times 3a^6b^{10}$$